# How to make svg animation with Animated in react-native

Tags: svg, react-native

ReactNative:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <Svg
      height="100"
      width="100">
        <Circle
          cx="50"
          cy="50"
          r="50"
          stroke="blue"
          strokeWidth="2.5"
          fill="green"/>
      </Svg>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to make Circle scale with Animated.Value. I have tried this :

```
    let AnimatedScrollView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);
    let AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);

    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Svg
              height="100"
              width="100">
                <AnimatedCircle
                  cx="50"
                  cy="50"
                  r={this.state.animator}
                  stroke="blue"
                  strokeWidth="2.5"
                  fill="green"/>
              </Svg>
        </ScrollView>
```

Then flash back with no error.

How can I do?

---

**update 2016.8.24**

I found a new way instead of requestAnimationFrame :

constructor:

```
this.state = {
      animator: new Animated.Value(0),
      radius: 1,
    };

    this.state.animator.addListener((p) => {
      this.setState({
        radius: p.value,
      });
    });
```

render:

```
<Circle
    cx="50"
    cy="50"
    r={this.state.radius}
    stroke="blue"
    strokeWidth="2.5"
    fill="green"/>
```

But here [the guides](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) gives advice using it sparingly since it might have performance implications in the future.

so what's the best way ?

Comment: I tried this approach but the listener was never getting called. I'm using React.createClass().

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this that doesn't involve updating the state with the listener? Thanks!

Comment: Found an ideal solution that makes use of your `addListener` but replaces `setState` with `setNativeProps` to make it **much** more performant.

Comment: What package do you use to render SVG's in RN?

Comment: Couldn't you just use transform: [{ scale: animatedValue }] on the Animated.View around it? Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No better answers, and I implemented by adding listener to `Animated.Value` variable, you can get more info from my question description.

Answer (score 23):

### Use `setNativeProps` for Much Better Performance.

I did some more tinkering and found a more performant method that makes use of `addListener` and `setNativeProps`.

**Constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { circleRadius: new Animated.Value(50) };

  this.state.circleRadius.addListener( (circleRadius) => {
    this._myCircle.setNativeProps({ r: circleRadius.value.toString() });
  });

  setTimeout( () => {
    Animated.spring( this.state.circleRadius, { toValue: 100, friction: 3 } ).start();
  }, 2000)
}
```

**Render**

```
render() {
  return(
    <Svg height="400" width="400">
      <AnimatedCircle ref={ ref => this._myCircle = ref } cx="250" cy="250" r="50" fill="black" />
    </Svg>
  )
}
```

**Result**

And this is what the animation looks like when the 2 second (2000 millisecond) timeout triggers.

[image: circle animation with setnativeprops]

So, the main thing you needed to change was using `setNativeProps` instead of using `setState` in your listener. This makes a native call and bypasses re-calculating the entire component, which in my case was very complex and slow to do.

Thanks for leading me towards the listener approach!

Comment: What about using `useNativeDriver` and `interpolate` so we don't have to use state? I need to do an animated SVG as well and want to try that.

Comment: @Noitidart Give it a shot and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Josh! :) I definitely will update you. Forgot to +1 this awesome solution of yours, did it now :)

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I have tried to implement an animation on the width and height of an svg in this way, I have it kind of working but it's performance is very poor and really bad when I have more than one running at a time. Do you have a full example of how you did this? @Noitidart do you have an example of using `NativeDriver` and `interpolate` so we don't have to use state?

Comment: @juliusbangert - I never dived into this. Am curious though on how its done.

Answer (score 2):

i have created a simple svg animations library based on a project by another person, for now, only Paths can be animated but more shapes and animations will be added in the future

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-animations