# Animate Svg.G using react-native Animated

Tags: animation, react-native

Taking inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094349/how-to-make-svg-animation-with-animated-in-react-native) answer, I implemented the following to rotate an Svg.G element. Based on setNativeProps to achieve a performant animation, this approach works for elements such as polygons and rectanges but not for the G element. The error I am getting states:
*You are setting the style `{ rotation: ... }` as a prop. You should nest it in a style object. E.g. `{ style: { rotation: ... } }`*
What is the correct way to implement this animation?

I have also come across another approach to animating Svg elements in this [repository](https://github.com/ethantran/react-native-examples/blob/master/src/screens/SvgGAnimation.js). However, this seems out of date.

```js
import { Animated } from 'react-native';
import Svg,{G} from 'react-native-svg';
const AnimatedG = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(G);

export default class RotatingControl extends Component {

    state = {
        animator: new Animated.Value(0),
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.animator,
            {
                toValue: 100,
                duration: 10000,
            }
        ).start();

        this.state.animator.addListener( ({value}) => {
            this._animG.setNativeProps({rotation: value.toString()});
            });
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
      <Svg 
      height="200" 
      width="100"
      >
      <AnimatedG
      ref={ref => { this._animG = ref; }}
      rotation="30"
      origin="100, 100"
      >
      <Polygon
        points="40,110 40,90 20,100"
        stroke="blue"
        strokeWidth="1"
        fill="grey"
      />
    }
    </AnimatedG>
    </Svg>
    )}
}
```